# copy a file from PC to thumb drive

Tags: ntfs, copy

I have a question about the Ubuntu file system.
    copy a file from PC to thumb drive. when file copy process is done(File Operations frame is off) , I unplug the thumb drive. and I found the file is not in the thumb drive, but if  I wait for a couple seconds, and then unplug the thumb drive. the file is in the thumb drive. why is there this status happened?
when File Operations frame is off, does it not mean the coping process finishes?
the file format of thumb drive is NTFS.
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21628/files-copied-to-flashdrive-only-on-unmount
if you properly unmount the drive the files should be flushed to the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Its because nautilus the file manager has some issues with writing data to USB sticks, its a known issue that it takes ages to sync the data to the disk.

If you need it faster you can use the command line , if you open a gnome-terminal and type cp then drop the file you want to copy on to the terminal and its fully qualified and quoted name will appear , just type the location you want the file to go to and press enter.